# How can i remove left and bottom Bar in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i have display the grid and lot of things in chart.js 3.2.1 version but i don't find the way to display this bar too , anyone have an issue pls ?

[The bar in arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgRmA.png)

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Réelle', 'Attendue'],
    options: {
      plugins:{
        legend:{
          display: false
        }
      },
     
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            display: false
          }
        },
        y: {
          ticks:{
            display:false
          },
          grid: {
            display: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to remove or add those bars?

Comment: Remove the bars indicated by the arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `drawBorder: false` option of the axis grid. Check the following example.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Réelle", "Attendue"],
    datasets: [
      {
        borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, .2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, .2)"],
        fill: true,
        data: [12, 19]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted so others can also know the correct solution.